# Change values of an array using the same object

Tags: java

Hey guys I am new in Java and i have a problem using arrays.This is my code

```
package exampleA;

public class exq {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dokimh p=new dokimh();
        double[] k=p.ex(5);
        double[] h=p.ex(0);
        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
            System.out.println(k[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

```
package exampleA;

public class dokimh {
    private double []d=new double[2];

    double[] ex(double a) {
        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
            d[i]=i+a;

        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me to understand why the values of k change when i use the array h and pass another value in my class??thank you!!

Comment: you should give more details, don't understand your question

Comment: you have to create a local variable for the array `d` in the method `ex` and not use a class variable which indeed is shared among `h` and `k`

Comment: I mean when i pass a value in my class and store it in k this value changes when i pass another value using double[] h=p.ex(0);

Comment: I found it thanx!!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because both `h` and `k` points to same instance (`dokimh.d` points on it too).

Comment: can you please give more details?I pass different values in ex method and store them in different arrays.So i cant understand why this is happening

Comment: @SpyrosArvanitis you only add a **reference** to the same array `d` in the object `p`

Comment: Also i tried the same code without using arrays(regural variables) and everything was fine(I mean h,k have different values as i want)

Comment: so if i create two objects will it be fine??like p1,p2?

Comment: @SpyrosArvanitis yes with two object it will work different. It works with `int` because `int` is primitive type it have different behavior.

Comment: @SpyrosArvanitis yes, but it would be even better if you just create the array `d` **inside** the method `ex`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same variable d in both cases. So it overrides the value, when you second time call p.ex() method. Use a local variable d,

```
public class dokimh {


     double[] ex(double a) {
        double []d=new double[2];
        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++) {
            d[i]=i+a;

        }

        return d;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`k` and `h` share the same array `d`: `d` is a member of `p` object and when you return it with `ex` function you are returning the same reference to it.
So here

```
double[] k=p.ex(5);
double[] h=p.ex(0);
```

`k` has a reference to `d` array member of `p` and the same happens with `h`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have created an object "p: it contain array of doubles called "d". 
In both cases when you call method to create k, or h array in the background you point to the array of "p" object. Your method's (how you've implemented them) are just pointers to the different array. So even if you call 10 timest the same method, and create different arrays (k, h, x, y, z...) in the background they refer always to the table which you created at the first time. It's lika an adress to the array, not new independence array itself.